# Calculating line integral over this vector field?

Tags: calculus

The path is the straight line from (1,1,1) to (2,-3,3). The force field is x^2yi +zj +(2x-y)k. I had the path as x(t)= (t+1,-4t+1,2t+1) from 0 to 1. The final answer I got was 20/3, but I'm not sure I set it up correctly, and would love some input as my book completely skips over how to figure out x(t) when it isn't explicitly given.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Your parametrization will definitely work.  Is that your only question?

Answer (score 0):

We note that if we have:

$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=x^{2}y\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}+z\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}}+(2x-y)\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$$

And our path $\Gamma : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$ parameterized as:

$$\Gamma(t) = (t+1)\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} + (-4t + 1)\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}} + (2t + 1)\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$$

We can thus write:

$$\begin{align*}
x(t) = t+1 &\implies \mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{d}t \\
y(t) = -4t+1 &\implies \mathrm{d}y=-4\:\mathrm{d}t \\
z(t) = 2t+1 &\implies \mathrm{d}z = 2\:\mathrm{d}t
\end{align*}$$

We note that in general for a path $\gamma:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^{3}$, we can write a path integral over $\vec{A}=A_{x}\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} + A_{y}\boldsymbol{\hat{\jmath}} + A_{z}\boldsymbol{\hat{k}}$ as:

$$\int_{\gamma}\vec{A}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r}=\int_{\gamma}\left[A_{x}\:\mathrm{d}x + A_{y}\:\mathrm{d}y + A_{z}\:\mathrm{d}z\right]$$

Thus we note that our path integral can be written as:

$$\begin{align*}\int_{\Gamma}\vec{F}\cdot \mathrm{d}\vec{r} &= \int_{0}^{1}\left[(t+1)^{2}(-4t+1)(\mathrm{d}t) + (2t+1)(-4\:\mathrm{d}t)+(2(t+1)-(-4t+1))(2\:\mathrm{d}t) \right]\\
&= -\int_{0}^{1}4t^{3}+7t^{2}-2t+1\:\mathrm{d}t = -\frac{10}{3}
\end{align*}$$

Which contradicts the answer in your textbook.

Comment: I should have clarified, the answer I got is the one I arrived at, not the textbook answer.

Comment: @tokola What did the textbook answer say?

Comment: It's just a practice problem in the book, the textbook gives no answer.